# Difference between word-wrap and word-break

Tags: html, css

When i have long url link, it breaks and overflow the parent container.

```
<a href="">http://www.example.com/somg-looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong-url</a>
```

To fix this, i tried to use either one of the following in CSS. Both of them works.

**word-wrap**

```
a {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**word-break**

```
a {
   word-break: break-all
}
```

What is the difference between **word-wrap** and **word-break**? which one is better than other?

Answer (score 1):

There is difference: word-wrap moves the whole word to another line, word-break just move what does not fit in previous line: http://goo.gl/6yt7zJ In your example, the result will be the same, because there is not space to move the whole word, but they both work different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference that you would likely notice, however word-wrap is the standard more commonly used one, and for a fun fact word-break exists as an alternative only to handle the word breaking of asian (Chinese, Japanese etc.) characters

Comment: Hello WongKongPhooey, just to clarify there is difference between them. Check my added answer http://goo.gl/6yt7zJ